# GS Conditional Formatting multiple range matching multiple values

Tags: regex, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, gs-conditional-formatting

On my Google Sheets document, I have two ranges with a dropdown list, and basically, I want to color cells according to the value selected of the dropdown list, but by a group of values.

Imagine the values possible are: toto, titi, tutu, foo, bar.

[image]

I would have **one rule** that apply a format on cells of **columns A and C** (A2:A11,C2:C11) that match **toto** or **foo**.

Comment: Would you please explain why it is essential that you would have "one rule"?

Comment: Simply to be easier to set up and maintain, currently I have one rule for each value, and I have 15 values in my case.

Comment: `=OR(A2:A11="foo",A2:A11="toto")`-this works as a conditional formatting custom formula for a single range in Column A. But if it is applied to both Column A and Column C (i.e. "one rule"), then a change in Column C also triggers a change in the adjacent cell in Column A (even if no value). Anyway, somewhere for you to start perhaps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use regex like this:

```
=REGEXMATCH(A2, "toto|foo")
```

[image: 0]

Comment: Thanks, that's it !